# ADC input impedance - DC682a with sensor

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, input-impedance, module, position-sensor

I need to read sensor position with 16 bit resolution, with this spec:
[image]

I currently have in hand the DC682A ADC, but Im not sure if I can use it  from datasheet LTC1859: "The input impedance is typically 42kΩ in unipolar mode and 31kΩ in bipolar mode, therefore, it should be driven with a low
impedance source."

Assuming I can't replace the ADC:

My question is - do I need to add series resistor ?( if the answer is yes please explain)
do I need to maybe add some buffer? (that required me to buy another module)
this is a part of schematic DC682A:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me.

The LTC1859 can be set to +/-5V input range and the sensor (although not clearly specified) certainly has an op-amp transimpedance stage, so it **is** a low impedance source.

Comment: I dont understand, if the voltage is 4V from the sensor that translates to 40uA(which means output resistance of 100kOhm) so when I try to measure the voltage it will see : Vadc=Vsource*R(ADC)/R(ADC)+R(100kohm) that will be something like 0.97V , am I wrong ?

Comment: Transimpedance amplifiers have a low output impedance. The feedback resistor would be 100K, but that does not affect the low output impedance of the amplifier.

Comment: I Still figure out to understance what you mean. what is the current will flow when the voltage is 4V from the position sensor? 40uA?

Comment: The current into the ADC chip will be the order of +/-100uA, which won’t affect the output significantly.